# Modifying Large JSON Files in Linux

Tags: text-editor, ide, javascript, json

I have a need to modify large JSON files that choke most editors (meaning: most editors will take a long time to open the file, and even after the file is loaded, the editor will become unresponsive while I'm attempting to make modifications).

The only program I've found, that can actually handle the files is [JSON Buddy](https://www.json-buddy.com/), but they don't offer a Linux version I can purchase. So, I'm having to run a Windows virtual machine to use this tool.

I suspect Linux does offer tools that can efficiently modify large files. However, JSON Buddy also provides some helpful features for formatting the JSON file in a manner that is human-friendly while editing.

I'm basically looking for a tool that can:

1. open large files instantly (because it doesn't have to load them into RAM before opening them).
2. present the json in an un-minimized well-formatted view during my
   modifications.
3. save the JSON file minimized.

If a tool like this exists, that runs on Linux, I have wallet in hand and I'm ready to make a purchase.

Please advise.

Comment: What's a "very large" JSON file's approx. size?

Comment: I'm looking for something that doesn't have to load the whole file in RAM to edit it. If you're the type of person who needs an exact size, then for you I say 4GB.

Comment: Try notepadqq https://notepadqq.com/wp/download/

Answer (score 1):

You might look at `Visual Studio Code`, found at https://code.visualstudio.com/. It's a good IDE (Integrated Development Environment), and has lots of helpful features.

Comment: Thank you, but Visual Studio Code requires the entire file to be loaded in RAM. I'm looking for a program that can navigate and edit the file without having to load the whole thing.

Comment: VS code says: tokenization, wrapping and folding have been turned off for this large file in order to reduce memory usage and avoid freezing or crashing. Also when trying to format: This file cannot be formatted because it is too large. When I force those features it freezes. ‍♂️

Comment: @Luckylooke Please start a new question.